# How many times was the Voyager self-destruct sequence activated?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

I'm re-watching *Voyager*, and just finishing Season 2 ("Basics, Part 1"). In this episode, Janeway tries to initiate the self-destruct sequence, but it fails to activate due to damage.

How many times was *Voyager*'s self-destruct activated (including failed attempts) over the course of the series? And in which episodes?

Comment: I suspect this would take a while to compile, but I'd love to see it. I bet it would be as ridiculous as their [photon torpedo inventory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIGxMENwq1k)

Comment: @crow like the Galactica, I'm sure Voyager had some way of building more torpedoes. Especially with replicator technology.

Comment: @cde The explicitly say in the pilot episode that they have no way to replace them, if that ever changed it wasn't mentioned in the show.

Comment: @crow Um um, no you shut up >___> Also, info in the pilot is never binding :) (I don't recall they said that honestly. Been so long.)

Comment: @crow just watched the video. 110 torpedoes over the + years they were out seems reasonable. Salvage some here and there, ingenuity to make more. The initial comment of no way to replace them is first year naivety. They just realized they were pulled in. And from TNG I think they stated or showed that standard probes and photon torpedoes use the same shell, the difference being the warhead. Idk, but I know they never addressed it on screen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we're limiting it to times they actually went so far as to activate the sequence then it's three:

*Basics Part 1* - as mentioned in the OP Capt. Janeway attempts to activate the sequence but is prevented from doing so due to the damage to the secondary command processors

*Dreadnought* - the sequence is activated as a last-ditch option to destroy Dreadnought but is aborted at the last moment due to B'Elanna succeeding in breaching the missle's containment field herself

*Deadlock* - activated and completed aboard one of the *Voyager's*, freeing the other copy in the process.

Comment: can you just add in what your source is for this? Is it just memory or were you able to find a listing?

Comment: It's from memory I'm afraid, I was quite an avid *Voyager* fan back in the day and I'm pretty confident in those being the only times the Self-Destruct sequence was used. The ship was *destroyed* a few more times than that (e.g. *Year of Hell Pt II, Timeless* & the Silver Blood copy that was destroyed in *Course: Oblivion*) and Janeway *threatened* to destroy it more times than I care to count but she either never went beyond threats or used alternative means such as in *Scientific Method*

Comment: I'm really terrified that a) you know the episodes by name, and b) this comment sounds so confident that I wouldn't dare dispute it.

Comment: @JohnnyBones yeah I'm a font of useless information and *Voyager* is one of my specialty subjects. Does it make it worse that I trimmed details from that comment (such as *how* those "destructions" of Voyager occurred and how they were all undone)? At times I hate my brain!

Comment: Congratulations, this is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49).